# How to view attribute information in shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a polygon shapefile (*.shp) and want to view its attribute data.

How can I do this using QGIS?

Comment: Yes but you would need to install it.

Comment: I already installed it but not exactly know how to use it instead of just adding the layer

Comment: View the attribute table. Is that the inside you speak about?

Comment: LOL.. yes you got it right!

Comment: So what is the question now?

Comment: no more question now. You shall move your comment to answer and I will mark it right

Comment: @jhyap mapsir has it right you can mark his answer. maybe he could add an image of said pulldown.  Also would you please put what it was you were looking for in your original question? just hit edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start QGIS.
Add vector layer by clicking on the icon marked in red box (e.g. Shapefile). See the image.
[image: Add vector layer by clicking on this icon marked in red box]

You can view the shapefile features in the map viewer part. And the layer will be listed in the LAYERS List (on the LHS in the image)
Right click the layer and "view attribute table" to view the attribute data associated with the shapefile(or any supported vector format).